# Vue.js passing data between components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to store input-value from App.vue, and use it in another component. How can I do it? I don't need the show the value in the template, I just need the value inside other components function. In JS I could just use a global var, but how can I achieve it in Vue?

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id='app'>
    <!-- App.vue has search bar -->
    <b-form-input @keydown='search' v-model='input'></b-form-input>
    <div>
      <!-- Here's my other components -->
      <router-view />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      input: '',
      value: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    search () {
      this.value = this.input
      this.input = ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Another component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>I'm another component</p>
    <p>App.vue input value was: {{value}} </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the basic logic I'm trying to achieve. Input value in App.vue --> anotherComponent.vue

Comment: Is anotherComponent.vue behind the route ?

Comment: Depend on the condition there are few ways that we can do this, 
1. use props if it is parent and child relationship
2. or else use vuex store
3. if router involved then use router params
4. can use event bus to pass your value as method parameter values and use it in other side (event bus is not build for this scenario not recom.. but can use)

Comment: The other component is behind my router, I'm passing the "name" in "route/:name", (that is the input value) but I'm also trying to store the :name -value into a variable so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If components are not parent and child you can use store for this:

1. More advanced `vuex` store that should be your default **GO TO** - [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex).
2. Or simple solution with js object.

   a. Create `store.js` file and export object with property in which you will store value.

   b. Import `store.js` object to vue scripts and use it simply like:

```
import Store from 'store.js'

Store.value
```

Comment: Thank you! Vuex solved my problem! `this.$store.state.value = this.input`